# 'Run as Different User' missing from Windows 10 context menu

Tags: windows, windows-10

It seems that the 'Run as different user' option is missing from the extended (shift+rclick) context menu.

On one of my computers, I can right click on any file, shortcut, executable, etc, and see the menu option.  But on this one computer the option is missing entirely, and only Run as Administrator is there.

How can I restore this context menu option?

Comment: Are these two computers different versions of Windows? I do not see "Run as Different User" on V20H2 or Windows Insider V21H something (newest).

Comment: @John winver both report that its 20H2 (19042.906)

Comment: There is also numerical limit to the number of options that can exist within the right-click context.  If that number is exceeded then any option beyond that number simply will not be displayed.  Please provide a screenshot of `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\batfile\shell\runasuser`, `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\cmdfile\shell\runasuser`, `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\exefile\shell\runasuser`, `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\mscfile\shell\runasuser`, and `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Msi.Package\shell\runasuser` as they appear in the Registry Editor.

Answer (score 3):

The method for the newest versions of Windows and beyond (Insider at this point), is to use Windows File Explorer, press and hold the Shift Key and then right click on the file.  "Run as Different User" appears.

I think this is the correct way forward looking both machines here.

I am not sure why one particular machine has this in the context menu as both my production machines and my Insider machine work as above.

Supporting article here:

[Run as Different User](https://winaero.com/run-app-different-user-windows-10/)

> To run an app as a different user in Windows 10, do the following.
>
> Open File Explorer and go to the folder which contains the required
> app.
>
> Press and hold the Shift key and right-click on the file. In the
> context menu, select Run as different user

Here is a screen shot:

[image]

Comment: But it doesn't show up when I do that, even in Explorer.

Comment: On the machine not working, try making sure it is right up to date and then restart the machine. I have tried the above on 3 machines.

Comment: FWIW, I see what @john describes when I Shift+RightClick an executible file but not with random "data" files ... pictures and the like.

Comment: For Data File, Run as Administrator does not normally apply. If I can Run Administrator and then Shift Right Click, I get Run as Different User.  I think it applies in these cases.

Answer (score 3):

The "Run as different user" Context Menu option might have been disabled.

To enable:

- Run the Local Group Policy Editor (`gpedit.msc`)
- Navigate to: User Configuration > Administrative Templates > Start Menu and Taskbar
- Check the option of: Show "Run as different user" command on Start.
  Verify that it's set to either Disabled or Not Configured.

Another setting which might apply to this problem:

- Run the Local Group Policy Editor (`gpedit.msc`)
- Navigate to: Computer Configuration > Administrative Templates > Windows Components >
  Credential User Interface
- Ensure that "Require trusted path for credential entry policy" is disabled
  or not configured.

Comment: Run as Different User was also around in Windows 7 so it is not new. I have looked on several real and virtual machines here and Run as Different User is not (from what I can see) enabled as Default.

Comment: @John: It's enabled on my computer, and I never did anything special to enable it or use it. Might depend on the Windows version.